# Changing view dimensions programmatically on android

Tags: android, layout, android-view

I have two views which overlap each other and one of them acts as a master to other. I am translating all the pinching and panning to scale and adjust the master view.
Now I wanna send this info over to the slave(Subclass of `android.view.View`). Being said that the other view doesn't respond to this dimensions. I have tried following methods

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();
params.height = height;
params.width = width;
this.setLayoutParams(params);this.requestLayout();

setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

this.setMinimumHeight(height);
this.setMinimumWidth(width)
```

None of these seem to work.

Using the onTouchEvent I resize my `TextureView` and send the same to the other View object. On getting this Info about change in size which is in most cases greater than the parent dimensions(and screen size) the other view should also increase/change its size.
The subclassed view doesn't grow to the dimensions supplied to it. Moreover the increase is limited to the parent size(in my case its width: 1080 height: 1776) while it can go above that in the textureView which uses

```
textureView.setMinimumWidth(newWidth);
textureView.setMinimumHeight(newHeight);
```

Any ideas as to what maybe going wrong or a trusted way to change layout/dimensions across two views?

Comment: Where are you putting these methods? You cannot get the dimensions in onCreate. You must use onWindowFocusChanged for these codes.

Answer (score 1):

- `setLayoutParams` => that would be the canonical way to position a View inside its parent.
- `setMeasuredDimension` => this is used from `View.onMeasure` to tell the layout system what size your particular View wants. Use only if you're implementing your own View subclass.
- `setMinimumWidth/setMinimumHeight` => tells the default View implementation what minimum size the View should have. If you implement `View.onMeasure` yourself, that shouldn't be needed.

All in all, if you stick with the standard Android framework components, `setLayoutParams` should be the place to look into.

Answer (score 0):

The methods you've listed are all valid ways of setting sizes if used correctly, and in the right situations.

This is difficult to solve without further information.

In what way isn't it working? Is it causing a crash, or are the view sizes just not what you expect?

Where does that snippet sit in your code? I would guess its part of a custom class of your own which extends ViewGroup, but as you're new to stackoverflow we have no idea of your level of programming experience. It might be in completely the wrong place, and `this` refers to some other object entirely.

One thing I **can** suggest you check :
You mention your slave is a subclass of `android.view.View`, but this on its own is not enough to be able to use ViewGroup.LayoutParams. You need to ensure your slave is a direct or indirect subclass of `android.view.ViewGroup`.

Provide more of your code and info on what you are observing, and we will try and help you further.

---

Update:
Ok, so it's a TextureView that you are trying to resize.

I'd recommend you check the reported size of your `TextureView` after you set it's height and width. You could do this with break-points and run a debug, or you could use `myTextureView.getWidth()`  and `.getHeight()`, and use `Log` statments to output them to the LogCat.
You can also check the size of the `SurfaceTexture` associated with your `TextureView`. Set a `SurfaceTextureListener` on your `TextureView`. When this listener is triggered, `onSurfaceTextureAvailable()` will provide the width and height of the `SurfaceTexture`.

I suggest this because you may find that you **are** able to change the size of the `TextureView`, but it is the **content** of the the `TextureView` that is not changing size. In this case you can override `TextureView.onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)` to define the necessary transform to scale your content between the old and new sizes.

Comment: instead of trying to change the size right now I am changing the canvas contents and drawing the data after applying transform matrix which i kinda tricky

Comment: I've added to my answer based on the new info you've provided.

Comment: `A TextureView is not a subclass of ViewGroup, so unfortunately you can't use setLayoutParams on it.` => Can you elaborate ? all Views should support `setLayoutParams`, including TextureView

Comment: @mbonnin You are correct. I have edited this old answer. Thank you.